# Can't run GitHub file through CMD on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to run a run a file from a GitHub repo using the Command Prompt on Windows. I started with these commands:

```
python -m pip install virtualenv
python -m virtualenv ocopus_venv
.\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
curl -O https://github.com/zuphilip/ocropy-models/raw/master/en-default.pyrnn.gz
move en-default.pyrnn.gz models
```

No errors so far, but when I run:

```
./ocropus-nlbin tests/ersch.png -o book
```

I got this error: the '.' is not recognized

How can I make this command run properly?

Comment: Hey @Mayyy make sure next tune you specify the tool you run and the OS you use, welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

On Windows cmd this doesn't work. Try without the `./` at the beggining. Condering [ocropy](https://github.com/ocropus/ocropy) supports Windows you can run it also wtih python2.7.

```
python ocropus-nlbin tests/ersch.png -o book
```

Don't forget you have to run `python setup.py install` before.